# firebase - email authentication mail does not have %DISPLAY_NAME%,

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been working on angularJS and firebase now.

An email goes out after registration to my website using the below piece of code:

```
regUser.sendEmailVerification();
```

The message for this email at firebase.google.com shows

> Hello %DISPLAY_NAME%,
>   Follow this link to verify your email address.

But the message which I recieve on my email after registration shows

> Hello , 
>   Follow this link to verify your email address.

It does not display the %DISPLAY_NAME% . What is wrong here? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like the user in that case doesn't have a display name.

Comment: How would I add a display name here? I tried using     regUser.setDisplayName(user.firstname) but this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `regUser.updateProfile(...)` to [update the user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile). Which allows you to set `displayName`:

```
regUser.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  regUser.sendEmailVerification();
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```